# I want call php page by clicking on a button but I want to verify it first through javascript that entered value is correct or not

Tags: javascript, php

```
<head>  
function search() {
    var n = document.getElementById("search");
    if(n === A || n === B) {
        location.href = "search.php";
        return true;
    } else {
        alert "Enter Correct value ...";
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
```

I'm using this code for verify entered value and after verification I want call php page to get the entered value for further task

```
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="search" onsubmit="search()" name="bg">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Okay, and what doesn't work?

Comment: Try adding a `<script>` tag after `<head>` and before you start writing javascript

Comment: what's the status of  this question? If one solved it, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what your asking!
If you are trying to get the value of the input field you need to change your document.getElementid("search");
To document.getElementid("search").value;
As this will be a string you will also need to change your if statement to make sure the value is equal to a 'A' ||'B'

Comment: function search() { var n = document.getElementid("search").value;
if(bloodgroup === 'a+' || 'A+' || 'aplus' || 'APLUS'){ return ture; } else { alert "Enter Correct"; return false;} }                                                                            It's not working.

Comment: Actually I want to get value from html page and I want to check the value using javascript and if entered value is correct then I want to go on Php page. Please help me out..!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code : **why you are not using opening script tag**

> < script > tag after < head >

```
<head>
</script>
function search() {
    var n = document.getElementById("search");
    if(n === A || n === B) {
        location.href = "search.php";
        return true;
    } else {
        alert "Enter Correct value ...";
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script>
    function search_bloodgroup(){

        var bloodgroup = document.getElementById("search").value; 
        if(bloodgroup ==="a+"|| bloodgroup ==="A+" || bloodgroup ==="aplus" || bloodgroup ==="APLUS"){
            alert("true");
            return true; 
        } 
        else { 
            alert("Enter Correct");
            return false;
            }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="search_bloodgroup()" action="">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="bg"></input>
    <input type='submit'></input>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This works fine hopefully this will help.